# vsts online pull request code how to remove dotted border

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

When I review code in VST online around every code line a dotted border is visible. Other team members don't have this behavior. How can I remove this kind of markup.

example:
[example code snippet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CCUy.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your profile, and change the UI Theme to `Default`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem. It was a bit confusing to find the correct profile settings. I needed to select the "Microsoft Account" in the combobox on my profile page. It seems you can have multiple profiles.

Comment: This helped me find the answer for TFS 2015, but for me it was under User Profile > General > UI Settings > Theme ...and changed it from "High Contrast" back to "Default"